# Subtract two non-numeric dataframes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, subtraction

I have two dataframes, with the same column names. I want to subtract one from another. So A-B should give me what is in A but also not in B. So A minus intersection of A and B. As show in the photo below.

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df1 = df1.append({'A': 'bmw','B':'three','C':'series'}, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append({'A': 'merc','B':'S','C':'class'}, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append({'A': 'Audi','B':'A','C':'eight'}, ignore_index=True)

df2 = df2.append({'A': 'merc','B':'ccc','C':'sss'}, ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left'))
```

The result I expect is:

```
{'A': 'bmw','B':'three','C':'series'} 
{'A': 'Audi','B':'A','C':'eight'}
```

But instead I get

```
{'A': 'merc','B':'ccc','C':'sss'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove rows where `df1['A']` is in the entire `df2['A']` series.

```
res = df1.loc[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]

print(res)

#       A      B       C
# 0   bmw  three  series
# 2  Audi      A   eight
```

Comment: It is yesterday dupe :(

Comment: will leave as community wiki to help the guy

Comment: @jpp I have no "key" column, the three columns (A,B,C) should be keys. This is how it is different from the original question